# (CSS) Link formed like that <=

Tags: html, css

I want to create an html link that has this form:

[image]

- when that link is hovered or focused that form should change its color.
- The text in the link should be in the center of the link, normally that would mean `display: block`.
- this mustn't have problems with using the same way to create a link the other direction in the same row. (I had problems with this when I used a technique with `position: relative`)

What I have already tried:

- making a normal row and then fixing divs with `height:0; width: 0; position: relative; top: 1.4rem; left: 0; border: 0.7rem solid white; border-right: 0.7rem solid transparent;`, for the other direction the opposite way, but the two divs above the row didn't appeared in the same height.
- making the triangles in the left not changing color when hovered or focused, but I didn't like that.
- instead of using the `border`-hack with `position: relative` I used floats to fix them. This didn't worked when I also wanted to have the linktext vertically centered.

Comment: Please include the HTML and CSS you've use to get as far as you have, in a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the shape using pseudo elements like `:before` and `:after`

```css
.box {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid #000;
  left: -50px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.box:hover {
  background: #eee;
  color: #000;
}

.box:hover::after {
  border-right: 25px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<a class='box'>Demo Link</a>
```

Comment: @Asqiir Added all of your requirements to the code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is there a good way to get the height of the link (== the width the border should have)? I guess using `100%` wouldn't refer to the link, `1rem` would be to small because the fonts height is 1rem, and there is no special word to get the boxes height, isn't there? (The link: `display: box`, `font-size: 1rem`, that's all what happened to the link)

Comment: Why do you want to get the height of the link ? It depends on on how big you want the box to be. @Asqiir

Comment: First I thought I would have to get it to have the border-width for the border-triangle in the left - then I realised it will be easier to set the height.